# Pandas TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, concatenation

Assume there are three .csv files in the directory: EX1.csv, EX2.csv, EX3.csv.

I have used the following code to merge them together.

```
import pandas as pd

EX1 = pd.read_csv('EX1.csv')
EX2 = pd.read_csv('EX2.csv')
EX3 = pd.read_csv('EX3.csv')

data = [EX1, EX2, EX3]
data = pd.concat(data)
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Once concatenation is used, the index numbers do not follow a gradual row numbering.

One of my goals is to make sure that the index numbers for the merged data-frame goes from 0 to (len(data) - 1). To make the index numbers follow a gradual increase from 0 to (len(data) - 1), I used the code below and got the TypeError.

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    data.index[i] = i
```

I would appreciate some advice on this please. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a para within `concat` `ignore_index`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1, 'a'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([2, 'b'])
pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
Out[873]: 
   0
0  1
1  a
2  2
3  b
```